# Knockoutjs containerless control flow

Tags: knockout.js, control-flow

I seem to have an issue with the containerless control flow. When the page is loaded initially it works correctly, when the field gu_catCnt is updated (I can see it in the model getting updated), the page is still static. The field is in the format: viewModel -> Fields -> [3] -> gu_catCnt,    Where [3] is the 4 element in an array - could this be the issue?

```html
<!-- ko if: ((parseInt(gu_catCnt) > 0)-->                                     
<select data-bind="options: gu_allCats,
      optionsValue: ca_Value,
      optionsText: ca_Text,
      selectedOptions: gu_Value,
      value: $data"</select>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it's working on page load and and doesn't update when the property changes, then `gu_catCnt` is probably a regular property and not an `observable`. Change it an observable:

```
gu_catCnt: ko.observable("0")
```

Comment: Thanks adiga, both fields are observable

Comment: Can you please share a [mcve]? A minimal jsfiddle or stack overflow snippet that reproduces this issue?